# R Find/Position Errors (funprog)

Tags: r, functional-programming

I am learning about R's `funprog` functions when I encountered a strange error I don't understand and see no comments online about.  Here is some toy data and a reproducible example.

```
 xs <- list(1, "bats", NA, NULL, 75)
 Find(is.na, xs) ## works as expected
 Position(is.na, xs) ## returns 3
 Find(function(xx){ xx == "bats" }, xs) ## works as expected
 Position(function(xx){ xx == "bats" }, xs) ## returns 2
 Position(function(xx){ xx == 1 }, xs) ## returns 1
 Position(function(xx){ xx == 75 }, xs)
 ##  Error in if (f(x[[i]])) return(i) (from #1) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed                                                                                                           
 s75test <- function(xx){ xx == 75 }
 Position(s75test, xs)
 ##  Error in if (f(x[[i]])) return(i) (from #1) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed                                                                                                           
 s75test(c(1, 75))
 ## FALSE  TRUE
```

So what concept am I missing about how Find/Position should work?  I can do string matching, testing for NA values and apparently number comparisons, provided that the number is `1` :P

EDIT: Some additional examples:

```
Position(is.null, xs) ## returns 4
xs2 <- xs[-4]
Position(function(xx){ xx == 75 }, xs2) 
##  Error in if (f(x[[i]])) return(i) (from #1) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: try `xs <- list(1, "bats", NULL, 75, NA)` and `Find` probably does not work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is because of the `NULL` and `NA` in `xs`.

Let us have a look at the function `Position` :

```
> Position
function (f, x, right = FALSE, nomatch = NA_integer_) 
{
    ind <- if (right) 
        rev(seq_along(x))
    else seq_along(x)
    for (i in ind) if (f(x[[i]])) 
        return(i)
    nomatch
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000efbca78>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

When `i=3` the error gets thrown because `xx==75` doesn't give `TRUE` or `FALSE` if `xx = NA`. For

```
Position(function(xx){ xx == "bats" }, xs) ## returns 2
Position(function(xx){ xx == 1 }, xs) ## returns 1
```

there was no problem because the return happens before the moment that the error would get thrown.

Conclusion: don't allow `NULL`or `NA` in your list, or write a function that handels `NULL` or `NA`.

Comment: Indeed the same problem happens with `NA`

Comment: @rawr -  `sapply(xs, function(xx){ xx == 75 })` does not error out.  What is the difference here?

Comment: The output of sapply doesn't need to be TRUE or FALSE, the output of the function entered in Position should be boolean